# ZLIB Golang и PHP различается

Tags: php, golang, zlib

Почему я получаю разный результат zlib на одном уровне сжатия (7) на обоих языках?
hex

PHP: 
`echo bin2hex(zlib_encode("test", ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE, 7)) . PHP_EOL;`
Результат: 
 `78da2b492d2e0100045d01c1`

Golang: 
 [image: zlib golang]

Результат: 
 `78da2a492d2e01040000ffff045d01c1`

Я разрабатываю программу где требуется такое же сжатие как на php, что можно сделать? Может я не ту библиотеку использую?

Comment: пробовал compress/flate, результат вообще другой по сравнению с php

Comment: предлагали вариант с 78da + raw zlib + adler32(raw zlib), но если так, то как получить raw zlib на golang?

Comment: В golang своя собственная реализация deflate — соответственно, другие алгоритмы, другие эвристики, другой результат — одинаковые результаты получатся скорее всего никогда. А если вы хотите идентичный результат (хотя зачем?) — нужно использовать идентичную реализацию, вроде бы вот это оно https://github.com/datadog/czlib

Comment: благодарю за ответ

Comment: пожалуйста, вставьте код текстом, а не картинкой. Если форматирование не очень - его поправят.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ от andreymal:
«В golang своя собственная реализация deflate — соответственно, другие алгоритмы, другие эвристики, другой результат — одинаковые результаты получатся скорее всего никогда.»
Реализация zlib на с биндингах:
https://github.com/datadog/czlib